# Command "wsl --version" gives "Invalid Command"

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've reinstalled wsl and am still getting the same error while following Microsoft's tutorial on WSL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/wsl-introduction/

When I open Powershell in Admin mode and try the command:

```
wsl --version
```

I get error:

```
Invalid command line option: --version
```

I can do `wsl -l` and get:

```
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu (Default)
```

and `wsl -l -v`:

```
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Stopped         2
```

My system:

Windows 11 Pro
Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621

Other commands that did work:

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
wsl --setdefault Ubuntu
```

Comment: Probably the tutorial is outdated.

Comment: I didn't want to assume the tutorial is wrong, but that's what it feels like.